# Navbar buttons stay inline on resize

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My navbar is displaying fine on fullscreen but i´m getting some problems when i resize my browser, i´ve attached some images, i wonder how to make the buttons `(Search Buttons)` inline even on resize!

```css
.btn-padding {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navcolor">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        
            <li className="nav-item btn-padding-40"></li>

            <li className="nav-item btn-padding-40">
               
            </li>

            <li className="nav-item btn-padding-45">
                <a className="nav-link page-title">SPRINTS</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="custom-select form-control btn-padding droppadding">
                    {optionItems}
             </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                 <form class="form-inline">
                    <input id="SearchTxt2"  className="form-control btn-padding" type="text" placeholder="Sprint ID"></input>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-padding" onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit2(e)} type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </li>    

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <input id="SearchTxt"class="form-control btn-padding" type="text" placeholder="Issue ID"></input>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-padding" type="submit" onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)} >Search</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Full screen** This is ok, it displays as it should

[image]

**Half-Screen** the buttons instead staying inline they pass under the inputs

[image]

**Collapse** The same happends on collapse, they go under the inputs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `input-group` for that.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="SearchTxt2"  className="form-control btn-padding" type="text" placeholder="Sprint ID">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-padding" onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit2(e)} type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

More details for `input-group`: [Click here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property `white-space` to `nowrap` to the parent div

```html
<!-- Now try to resize your screen using developer tools or simply resizing the window -->
<div style="white-space: nowrap">
       <input type="text" />
       <button>OK</button> 
</div>
```